# Find out count of employees joined in January month

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

How to fetch only january row from this output?

```
select to_char(hire_date,'month'),count(employee_id)
from employees
group by to_char(hire_date,'month')


TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'MONTH')           COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID)
------------------------------------ ------------------
march                                                17
january                                              13
february                                             13
june                                                 11
august                                                9
december                                              7
july                                                  7
april                                                 7
october                                               6
may                                                   6
september                                             5
november                                              5
```

Comment: use where clause to filter jan record and then count

Comment: Its not working in that way

Comment: post that query which you tried

Comment: Format your question text please and post the query you tried.

Comment: I used  select to_char(hire_date,'mon'),count(employee_id)
from employees
group by to_char(hire_date,'mon')
having to_char(hire_date,'mon')='jan'...then its displaying Jan data, but when i am using month format, its not displaying jan data

Comment: use Trim or fm (in to_char format) in where clause. to_char of Month will work based on September (max length month name), other month will have space if you use to_char. To avoid that we have to use fm in to_char or we can use trim

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT   to_char(hire_date, 'month') ,
         COUNT(employee_id)
FROM     employees
WHERE   EXTRACT(month FROM hire_date) =1
GROUP BY to_char(hire_date, 'month');
```

Comment: there is no month() in Oracle

Comment: my bad, Looks like Oracle has Extract function to do the same. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, I presume, in "incorrect" date format mask. Have a look at this example:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'month') mon,
  2    length(to_char(sysdate, 'month')) len_mon,
  3    --
  4    to_char(sysdate, 'fmmonth') fmmon,
  5    length(to_char(sysdate, 'fmmonth')) len_fmmon
  6  from dual;

MON          LEN_MON FMMON      LEN_FMMON
--------- ---------- --------- ----------
july               9 july               4

SQL>
```

See? `'month'` format mask results in `'july     '` (right padded to 9 characters in length), so you should either `TRIM` it, or use another format mask (such as `'fmmonth'`), or use its numeric representation (January is "1").

So, if you used

```
where to_char(hire_date,'fmmonth') = 'january'
```

you'd, probably, get the result.

Comment: Littlefoot on fire! just like their football team :-)

Comment: Hello, @Kaushik! I'm not any kind of a football expert, but - in my opinion, we played better football, had many more goal chances than England and deserved victory. So - thank you!

Comment: Agreed.Not an expert myself either.Nevertheless, you scored  well with Oracle on that occasion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select 
  to_char(hire_date,'month') as hire_month,
  count(employee_id) 
from 
  employees 
where
  hire_month = 'january'
group by 
  to_char(hire_date,'month')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use direct date comparison:

```
select 'January', count(employee_id)
from employees
where hire_date >= date '2018-01-01' and
      hire_date < date '2018-02-01';
```

This is better because it can take advantage of an index on `employees(hire_date)`.

Also note the inclusion of year.  When working with months, we almost always want to consider the year as well.  If you just want january numbers from any year, then use your `to_char()` expression.